# Boost's is_any_of causes compile warning?

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following lines in my code:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
boost::split(lines, output, boost::is_any_of("\n"));
```

Where `output` is a `const std::string`.

When I compile, I get an error:
`error: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'typename range_difference<iterator_range<const char *> >::type' (aka 'long') to 'std::size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Werror,-Wsign-conversion]
                    std::size_t Size=::boost::distance(Range);`

This originates from

```
 boost::split(lines, output, boost::is_any_of("\n"));
                                    ^
```

Seems like an internal typing error in boost?
Anyone encountered this before?

Note: Compiling with gcc version 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), most warning flags set and -Werror.

Note2: So as @sehe has shown, this is indeed a boost issue.
So let me change the question - Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `output`? What is `lines`, really? Because how do you split a ... collection of strings? (In other words, make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: It is almost impossible to compile something using boost without warnings caused by boost guts. It looks like someone forgot to use static_cast at `std::size_t Size=::boost::distance(Range);`.

Comment: @VTT that's a weird statement. I'm guessing you're using MSVC then, in which case you can include a header to disable these warning. PS. Did you reproduce the error? Do you have a SSCCE/MVCE to repro?

Comment: @immortal Can you make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @sehe I would say that MSVC is somewhat more permissive (and often much more suppressed with #pragma warning inside of boost) and emits less warnings than clang and gcc.

Comment: @VTT after realizing that -Wall -Wextra -pedantic doesn't enable all warnings [sic] I can see what you mean. Thanks for showing :)

Comment: @sehe Another thing is that on linux machines using boost that is installed system-wide somehow inhibits quite a lot of warnings that would pop if boost include path is explicitly provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as there's no more activity around this issue I'll close this with saying that yes - this is a boost issue. It's easily reproduced with @sehe 's MCVE.
Apparently compiling boost with strict warnings and Werror flags is impossible.

As per my workaround, I had a fairly simple use-case and I've implemented my own, simple, version of split

```
inline std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string &str, char delim)
{
  std::vector<std::string> out;
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  std::string item;
  while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
      out.push_back(item);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced issue

https://wandbox.org/permlink/LIf0wzUPQxrz7pik (GCC) and https://wandbox.org/permlink/BofswARbx1BpVE6H (Clang)

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string output;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    boost::split(lines, output, boost::is_any_of("\n"));
}
```

This should be reported to the maintainers of Boost Algorithm (see the boost mailing list or https://svn.boost.org/trac10/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&component=string_algo&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=milestone&order=priority)

Comment: You didn't add `-Wsign-conversion`

Comment: @VTT Ah. You're quite right. The OP might have specifically mentioned this. Yeah, I agree it's a problem reportable to boost.